In input-remapper, how do I associate scroll wheel with Ctrl-+ and Ctrl--?
I would like to use scroll wheel to the "make everything bigger/smaller" functions, traditionally associated with "Ctrl and +" and "Ctrl and -" keys.
How I do this in input-remapper ? AFAIK there's no symbol for "+" key. I can only see a symbol called "minus". At least there's no symbol associated with this key in input-remapper-control --symbol-names list.
I've tried the following sequences:
Control_L + +
Control_L + -
Control_L + wheel(up, 10)
Control_L + wheel(down, 10)
Control_L + minus
Control_L + plusminus

None of them worked. The scrollwheel just rolls the page as normal.

Moderators: I used the "keyboard-shortcuts" tag because I couldn't find a better one. If it's wrong please suggest/edit a better one. Thanks.

User JonasBoss helped me in the input-remapper issues. This is the correct procedure:
1 - Configure Wheel disabled:

add a new mapping
record any scroll wheel move.
press Advanced button.
remove Wheel Up/Down event leaving only Wheel HI RES +/- event.
Check Use as analog.
put disable in the output.

2 - Configure Wheel Up:

add a new mapping
record Wheel Up event. It will apear as Wheel Up + Wheel HI RES +.
press Advanced button .
there will be 2 events: Wheel Up and Wheel HI RES +.
select Wheel Up and press "Remove this input" button leaving only Wheel HI RES +.
put Control_L + KEY_KPPLUS in the output field.

3- Configure Wheel Down:

same procedure as above substituting the event names by Wheel Down and Wheel HI RES - and Control_L + KEY_KPMINUS for the output field.

Hope this helps someone.
